# Converting HQL to SQL

Tags: sql, hql

I'm trying to understand HQL and its similarities with SQL.

I have the following in HQL:

```
  select distinct src_ip b, 'src_ip' b_name
  from ${table}
```

My question is, what is the 'src_ip' b_name referring to? It's not part of the schema, and I've not seen this syntax. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a standard SQL.
The 1st column would hold the values of `src_ip` and the column alias would be `b`.
The 2nd column would hold the hard-coded string `'src_ip'` and column alias would be `b_name`